login error: Flask Authentication Code Not Finding Username in Database After Project Migration
I am currently working on a Flask application and I have encountered an issue with the authentication code that I previously used in another application. The code was functioning correctly in the original project, but when I copied it over to a new project, I faced an error stating that it cannot find the username in the database, even though it is indeed present.
python 3.12
How fix it ?
app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'  # Указываем представление для входа
login_manager.login_message = 'Please log in to access this page.'

migrate = Migrate()


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    from models import User
    from routes import main_routes, user_routes, admin_routes, article_routes, meeting_routes, test_routes, \
        favorite_routes, bookmarks_routes,auth_routes

    app.register_blueprint(main_routes)
    app.register_blueprint(user_routes)
    app.register_blueprint(admin_routes)
    app.register_blueprint(article_routes)
    app.register_blueprint(meeting_routes)
    app.register_blueprint(test_routes)
    app.register_blueprint(favorite_routes)
    app.register_blueprint(bookmarks_routes)
    app.register_blueprint(auth_routes)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))
    
    return app

models.py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        # Assuming all users are active unless specified otherwise
        return True

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True  # You might want to adjust this logic based on your session management

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return True  # Already added, but ensure it's correct

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False  # Typically false for authenticated users

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(150), index=True, unique=True)  # Изменено на username
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, default='user')  # Новое поле для роли
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
    articles = db.relationship('Article', backref='author', lazy=True)
    favorite_articles = db.relationship('Article', secondary='favorites', backref='favorited_by')
    bookmarked_articles = db.relationship('Article', secondary='bookmarks', backref='bookmarked_by')
    meetings = db.relationship('Meeting', backref='creator', lazy=True)

    def set_password(self, password_hash):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password_hash)

    def check_password(self, password_hash):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password_hash)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)


auth.py
@auth_routes.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user and user.check_password(form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page or url_for('main.index'))
        else:
            flash('Invalid username or password')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)

Here are some details about the situation:

The authentication code is identical to what I used in the previous project.
The library versions in both projects are the same.
The database connection is functioning correctly. Records are being created during registration, and the debug output shows the names of all users upon query.
The username exists in the database.

